# GPG errors from dnf on linux9

Tags: linux, dnf, gpg-signature

Recently installed Rocky Linux9 on a bunch of machines. No real problems except for some packages don't want to install.

Example: confluent-kafka-2.11. If I run `dnf install confluent-kafka-2.11 -vv` I get the usual downloading info but it ends with

```
Using rpmkeys executable at /usr/bin/rpmkeys to verify signatures
Problem opening package confluent-kafka-2.11-2.0.1cp8-1.noarch.rpm
The downloaded packages were saved in cache until the next successful transaction.
You can remove cached packages by executing 'yum clean packages'.
Error: GPG check FAILED
```

I've tried adding --nogpgcheck but it still doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Same problem with elasticsearch except I was able to manually install the gpg key. This won't work as soon as the package updates though.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple solutions here.

To actually solve the gpg issue, the question is, how did you add the repo and the gpg key?

What is the output of

```bash
sudo dnf list all | grep confluent
# and
sudo dnf repolist
```

Comment: The gpg keys won't install. I ended up downloading the rpm and doing a local-install. Same issue with some other sites like elasticsearch.